# How to Stop Skype auto updates for Skype version 8.29.0.50

Tags: skype

I recently updated skype to the Skype version 8.29.0.50. Ever since this update, skype forces updates every week. I wanted to disable auto updates, but could not find an option to do so. Please suggest a way to disable auto skype updates for the Skype version 8.29.0.50. I am using windows 7 Professional.

Comment: If Skype isn't up-to-date, sooner or later, it will stop working.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - tbh, it's pretty much stopped working properly since v8. <rant> I file new bug reports with each new version & so far none of them has been fixed. That aside, it looks like someone liberally sprinkled it with jelly tots... designed by [or for] a 4-year-old. </rant> ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I ditched Skype years ago, before the issues you mentioned. At the time I was attending a (college sponsored) conference where the organizers "forced" everybody wanting to have lunch and dinner at the event to confirm via Whatsapp. Since then Whatsapp is all I and my extended social network use.

Comment: Ditching Skype is not an option I have. This is the only tool that my company allows for remote communications. This Skype update is stupid as in all Skype is. I would even love to use Whatsapp, for there are restrictions here, which don't allow me to use it. If anyone has figured out how to disable the update or to roll back to an older version that has Auto-updates turned off, would be a great help.

Comment: @Rahul if you're willing to downgrade Skype, please state that *in your question*, not in the comments. Comments get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to disable auto update of Skype 8.x in Windows 7.
It appears this process is controlled by skype-setup.exe, but even if you delete this file, it will be repopulated if Skype cannot find it. Sneaky! So here's a workaround drived from user GPO:
1. Quit Skype / make sure Skype is not running; 
2. Find the directory with the file skype-setup.exe, mine was in folder users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\;
3. Delete the file skype-setup.exe or rename it to skype-setup-old.exe or similar;
4. Create a new folder in this directory and name it skype-setup.exe;
5. Done.